# Combining Ansible with Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, ansible, provisioning

In talks and meetups most people use ansible and vagrant together to test stuff on their computers. I now worked through the tutorials for both but it seems they haven't put much thought into that idea in these tutorials. I know [there's an ansible provisioner for vagrant](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/ansible.html) but it's the wrong way around I think. I would think that I don't want to interact with each VM separately, but using ansible to provision them all with one playbook and one shell command. Is that possible? Does it require some special setup?

Answer (score 2):

Your `vagrantfile` can contain info about multiple VMs.

Alternatively, don't use any provisioner when you create VMs and then use ansible to configure them all in one go.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's possible and here is working example that might help you to understand that how you can run the separate playbook on different servers at once without interacting with the servers.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.box_check_update = false
  config.ssh.insert_key = false

  # Web Server Configuration
  config.vm.define "webserver" do |webserver|
      webserver.vm.hostname = "webserver"
      webserver.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.50"

      webserver.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
             # Do not load the command line GUI
             vb.gui = false

             # Virtual Machine Name
             vb.name = "webserver"

             # Network settings
             vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
                 vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnsproxy1", "on"]

             # Use VBoxManage to customize the VM
             vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "512"]
      end

      # Configuration for Ansible as Provisioner
      webserver.vm.provision :ansible do |ansible| 
        ansible.playbook = "webserver.yml"
        ansible.host_key_checking = false
      end
  end

  # Database Server Configuration
  config.vm.define "database" do |database|
      database.vm.hostname = "database"
      database.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.100"

      database.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
          # Do not load the command line GUI
          vb.gui = false

          # Virtual Machine Name
          vb.name = "database"

          # Network settings
          vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
          vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnsproxy1", "on"]

          # Use VBoxManage to customize the VM
          vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "1024"]

      end

      # Configuration for Ansible as Provisioner
      database.vm.provision :ansible do |ansible| 
        ansible.playbook = "database.yml"
        ansible.host_key_checking = false
      end
  end

end
```

If you want to run one playbook to all the servers at once, then you can do like this:

- Remove seperate `provision` block
- add this one `provision` block before last `end` statement

  `config.vm.provision :ansible do |ansible|`

  ```
   ansible.playbook = "playbook.yml"
   ansible.host_key_checking = false
   end
  ```

Hope this will help you.